How to do Active Sorting for the third time when the user clicks Column Header for Server Side Sorting of Data
I am using Angular and Angular Material
In this Material Grid has sorting option where there are 3 columns. While loading for the first time, it sorts by Id column where other columns are Name and Address. The First Click of the Column Header Name shows the data in Ascending order. Second click of the same column will show the data in descending order. The third click will give sortDirection property as empty '' and it retains the previous state of the Grid. This is the logic for Client Side Sorting.
Now I want to implement the same logic for Server-Side Sorting where API Backend is doing the pagination.

When the data is loaded for the first time, it sorts by Id column
When Name Column Header is clicked for first time, it shows in asc order
When Name Column Header is clicked for second time, it shows in desc order

Until now it is ok.

When the Address Column Header is clicked for first time, it sorts by Address column in asc order

When the Address Column Header is clicked for second time, it sorts by Address column in desc order

Now comes the real problem. When the user clicks Address column Header, the sortDirection becomes empty. Based on this, I need to show the previous state of the Grid. Like sorting by Name in Descending order. But it should NOT retain the state of the column header sorting by Id because we need to sort based on the recent previous state.
   handleSortChange(sort: Sort)
     {
       if(sort.direction === '') {
         this.sortBy = this.previousSortBy;
         this.sortDirection = this.previousSortDirection;
     } else {
       if(this.sortBy !== sort.active || this.sortDirection !== sort.direction) {
         if(this.sortDirection !== '') {
           this.previousSortBy = this.sortBy;
           this.previousSortDirection = this.sortDirection;
         }
         this.sortBy = sort.active;
         this.sortDirection = sort.direction;

         localStorage.setItem('sortBy', this.sortBy);
         localStorage.setItem('sortDirection', this.sortDirection);
         localStorage.setItem('previousSortBy', this.previousSortBy);
         localStorage.setItem('previousSortDirection', this.previousSortDirection);
       }
     }

     this.loadData();

}
 ngOnInit() {
   this.sortBy = localStorage.getItem('sortBy') || 'Id';
   this.sortDirection = localStorage.getItem('sortDirection') || 'asc';
   this.previousSortyBy = localStorage.getItem('previousSortBy');
   this.previousSortDirection = localStorage.getItem('previousSortDirection');

}


This code is not working. Somewhere, I am missing something.
How can I do that?
